# how to serialize function depending on what instance of object calls it, if same instance call in a thread then do serialize else not

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, synchronization, thread-safety

I have a deposit function which is called by multiple clients at same time. I want the deposit function synchronized when same client (say client with id=someUniqueNo) calls it again but not synchronized when other client else call it ? How can I achieve this.
Using Spring framework in the project , Its cool even if any solution with the framework provides for such pattern.

Comment: What do you want to do when a client makes its second call? Block until the first one finishes? Skip execution of that call?

Comment: If one caller locks the method or block of code, they all have to.  If you have one client which doesn't need it, it is likely that none of them need it.  What is the reason you want to avoid synchronization.  Don't tell me it performance related because correctness is always more important than performance and unless you are perform millions of update its unlikely to matter.

Comment: @Mister Smith  When the same client makes second call , it should wait till ongoing execution . I am still searching the solution , pls help if u can

Comment: @LondonDreams A thread-safe code for your problem is not a trivial thing.

Comment: @LondonDreams - pls see my second attempt code though I have not tested it myself.

Comment: `@LondonDreams` See edited version of my answer.

Comment: Posted an updated solution - my 3rd update - This is tested to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void deposit(String clientId){
   String id = clientId;
   while(id.equals("someClientID")){
         synchronized(lockObject){
             // Do your stuff here in a sync'd way
          }
   }
   else
   {
     // Do your stuff here in a NON synch'd way 
   }

 }
```

---

Second attempt : ( not tested !)

```
public void deposit(String clientId){
    String id = clientId;
   // callers is a ConcurrenthashMap<String,String>
     while(callers.get(id) != null){  
     synchronized(callers.get(id)){  // client already in call, so wait
        wait(); 
     }
   }       
      callers.put(id,id);  // client is ready to run a new call, so setup 
      // Do your stuff here in a NON synch'd way 
 synchronized(callers.get(id)){  // client done with a call , 
                      //so notify others who are calling
    callers.put(id,null);
    notifyAll();
       }
}
```

---

Third attempt ( tested and working correctly )

```
    public class SyncTest {
     static int[] balances = new int[]{ 1,10,100,1000,10000};
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SyncTest test = new SyncTest();
    Client c1 = new Client("0", test,1);
    Client c2 = new Client("1", test,10);
    Client c3 = new Client("2", test,100);
    Client c4 = new Client("3", test,1000);
    Client c5 = new Client("4", test,10000);

    Thread[] threads = new Thread[5];
    threads[0] = new Thread(c1);
    threads[1] = new Thread(c2);
    threads[2] = new Thread(c3);
    threads[3] = new Thread(c4);
    threads[4] = new Thread(c5);

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        threads[i].start();
    }
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        try{
            threads[i].join();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ex){
        }
    }


    System.out.println("Final balances are ");
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        System.out.print(balances[i] + " , " );
    }
}

ConcurrentHashMap<String,String> callers = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();

public void deposit(Client c) throws InterruptedException{
    String id = c.id;
    int amount = c.amount;
    if(id == null) return ;

   // callers is a ConcurrenthashMap<String,String>
    System.out.println("Client " + id + " in deposit. Checking if already running..");
    while( callers.get(id) != null && !(callers.get(id).equals("X"))) {
       synchronized(id){
        System.out.println("Client " + id + " in deposit. Found already running,going to wait..");
        id.wait(); 
     }
   }
    if(callers == null){
        throw new NullPointerException("Callers is null!!");
    }

    System.out.println("Client " + id + " in deposit. Found not running already,  Now running..");
    callers.put(id,id);
    int index = Integer.parseInt(id);
    balances[index] += amount;
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    synchronized(id){
        String old = callers.put(id,"X");
        id.notifyAll();
       System.out.println("Client " + id + " in deposit. Finished running ,  Notifying..");
    }
}

static class Client implements Runnable {
    String id ;
    SyncTest test;
    int amount;
    Client c = this;

    Client(String id , SyncTest t, int am){
        this.id = id;
        test = t;
        amount = am;
    }

    public void run(){
        process();
    }

    void process(){
        System.out.println("Client " + id + " processing ...");
        try{
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            Thread t1 = new Thread(
                new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        try{
                            test.deposit(c);
                        }
                        catch(InterruptedException ex){
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
            Thread t2 = new Thread(
                    new Runnable(){
                        public void run(){
                            try{
                                test.deposit(c);
                            }
                            catch(InterruptedException ex){
                            }
                        }
                    }
                );

            Thread t3 = new Thread(
                    new Runnable(){
                        public void run(){
                            try{
                                test.deposit(c);
                            }
                            catch(InterruptedException ex){
                            }
                        }
                    }
                );

            Thread t4 = new Thread(
                    new Runnable(){
                        public void run(){
                            try{
                                test.deposit(c);
                            }
                            catch(InterruptedException ex){
                            }
                        }
                    }
                );

        /*  Thread t5 = new Thread(
                    new Runnable(){
                        public void run(){
                            try{
                                test.deposit(c);
                            }
                            catch(InterruptedException ex){
                            }
                        }
                    }
                );

            Thread t6 = new Thread(
                    new Runnable(){
                        public void run(){
                            try{
                                test.deposit(c);
                            }
                            catch(InterruptedException ex){
                            }
                        }
                    }
                );
            Thread t7 = new Thread(
                    new Runnable(){
                        public void run(){
                            try{
                                test.deposit(c);
                            }
                            catch(InterruptedException ex){
                            }
                        }
                    }
                );
            Thread t8 = new Thread(
                    new Runnable(){
                        public void run(){
                            try{
                                test.deposit(c);
                            }
                            catch(InterruptedException ex){
                            }
                        }
                    }
                );
        */  
            t1.start();t2.start();t3.start();t4.start();//t5.start();t6.start();t7.start();t8.start();
            t1.join();t2.join();t3.join();t4.join();//t5.join();t6.join();t7.join();t8.join();

        }
        catch(InterruptedException ex){
            System.out.println(" Exception " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("Client " + id + " done #####");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This is not what it is asked here. The problem is not to allow a client entering the method more than one time, but we don't know in advance its ID.

Comment: @Mister Smith , "The problem is not to allow a client entering the method more than one time" - Where is the requirement stated in the question ? OP mentions he wants the method to be *synch'd* on reentrant calls, but not for first time callers - This is not same as what you commented - The reentrant call *has to* enter the method for it to be synchronized in any way !

Comment: Ok, entering and waiting, but the problem with your code is that literal value "someClientID", which is not known in advance. This is not about banning a single client.

Comment: Request the downvoter to pls give a reason. I am fine with you finding falut in my code , but pls let me know what it is!

Comment: I'm not the new downvoter since I can't downvote again. But you are synchronizing on an object that may be null, and also you are storing every new client without ever cleaning up the map. Your wait/notify on some object stops every thread. You are mixing synchronized with wait/notify, and also synching on the map that is already ConcurrentHashMAp. I could go on and on but I don't want to think more about all the bad things that can happen running that.

Comment: Well well , for the starters , I do not claim that this code is robust in every aspect. It attempts to show the broad manner in which the requirement stated by OP may be addressed. Obviosly issues relating to concurrency will have to be ressolved further.

Comment: @Mister Smith 1.  Null checks need to added 2. Client objects that are done finally need to be removed ( I did not do tat because that would need the knwoledge of when they are done ) 3.  Wait/Notify will not stop every thread - only if the id of the caller is found in the map then it will be stopped  - how do you say every thread will be stopped ? 4 . I am not synching on ConHashMap , I am synching on the Id returned by the get() on the map

Comment: Man, I give up. Now you have introduced a new feature: infinite loop. Please don't post broken code or code not tested.

Comment: @Mister Smith , Sorry about being so frustrating to you , this time I posted the code that runs and works properly ! Ofcourse there are a few improvements.

Answer (score 3):

Would something like this work?

```
private Map<String, ReentrantLock> lockMap = new HashMap<String, ReentrantLock>();

public void deposit(String clientId) {
    updateLockMap(clientId);

    ReentrantLock lock = lockMap.get(clientId);
    try {
        if(lock.tryLock(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)) {
            // do deposit stuff
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // log
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}

private void updateLockMap(String clientId) {
    if(!lockMap.keySet().contains(clientId)) {
        lockMap.put(clientId, new ReentrantLock());
    }
}
```

Comment: may be its seems working but problem is there are too many requests to the method at same time and checking into map slows down process.

Comment: Obviously don't know your requirements but would have thought if a simple map look up is causing performance issues then it's going to be very difficult. In fact I think you would need to synchronize the updateLockMap method - which of course would slow it down further.

Answer (score 2):

Not with the `synchronized` keyword, that's for sure. The built-in synchronization primitives know how to adjudicate between different threads and nothing more - they can't make the decision based on the value of parameters to a method. What you want to do is a synchronized message queue for each client or something equivalent, and have your function called only from that queue.

Comment: The simplest possible solution is to do as michid suggested. Assuming your customer has a unique customer number, have a `Map<String,Lock>` that is lazily populated when a request comes in, get the corresponding lock from the Map, and write your method call inside a `synchronized` block for that Lock.

Answer (score 2):

I would disagree with your assumption that two threads can access the same value without both being synchronized (or exclusively locked in some way).

If you have an update happening then you must ensure that all methods for updating AND READING the values are exclusively locked, otherwise chaos ensues. If you don't have these locks, then you can get partial or incorrect results.

Say you have a process like:

1. Update list of transactions
2. Update balance

Thread 1 starts the process, and does 1. The second thread READS (just reads) the list of transactions and balance. Thread 2 completes the process, and finishes.

Now thread 2 has an inconsistent view of the state of the account. The list does not match the balance. This is just an example, but it illustrates the problem.

It does not matter whether the first caller calls the request multiple times or you have multiple callers. All accesses to your data need to be synchronized. If you are in the process of changing something, then you need to present a consistent view to everyone, which means synchronizing.

Comment: Yes you are right but untold truth is - deposit function has a couple of db call in turn .

Answer (score 1):

Use a lock per client. That is, instead of synchronizing the method directly use explicit locking through lock objects. Arrange it such that you have one lock per client which you use to synchronize access to the deposit function.

Comment: How could that be achieved? Using a Map<String,Lock>? How would the wait and the map cleanup look like?

Comment: @Mister Smith: That depends on the details of your application. You could either lock on the user object directly given it is guaranteed to be the same instance every time. Alternatively you could provide the lock through the user instance. Or you could use a map as you suggested.

Answer (score -1):

You can do:

```
Client lock = yourClient;
synchronized (lock) {

}
```

Obtain the lock on the client same reference.

Comment: Again, the id is not know in advance. Read the question. It says how to serialize calls for a client, without affecting the calls of other clients..